# Django container CSRF verification fails

Tags: python, django, portainer

I made a container of my Django application and when I log in the app I get this error:

Origin checking failed - https://127.0.0.1:8443 does not match any trusted origins.

When I run the app in my pc I can log in without any issue. This error only occurs in the container.

I declared in my compose file to trust the ip but still get the same error:

DJANGO_CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: https://127.0.0.1:8443

This is my compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  
  my_app:
    container_name: my_app
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 my_app.wsgi
    depends_on:
      - my_app_postgresql
    environment:
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: DJANGO_SECRET_KEY
      DJANGO_DEBUG: '1'
      DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: '127.0.0.1'
      DJANGO_DATABASE_NAME: my_app_db
      DJANGO_DATABASE_HOST: my_app_postgresql
      DJANGO_DATABASE_PORT: '5432'
      DJANGO_DATABASE_USER: my_app_user
      DJANGO_DATABASE_PASSWORD: my_app_password
      DJANGO_CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: https://127.0.0.1:8443
    volumes:
      - my_app_volume:/my_app/static
      - my_app_volume:/my_app/media
    networks:
      - my_app_network
    image: my_app:latest
    
  my_app_postgresql:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: my_app_postgresql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRESQL_USERNAME: my_app_user
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: my_app_password
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: my_app_db
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgresql_data:/postgresql
    networks:
      - my_app_network

  my_app_nginx:
    image: bitnami/nginx:latest
    container_name: my_app_nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
```

Comment: Can you please add code as example